# redirect form view when open from tree view based on state

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

i created 3 different forms view (draft_view.xml, progress_view.xml, and done_view.xml) and i created statusbar='draft,in_progress,done'. But when i open record from tree view it always on draft_view.xml even the statusbar already move to in_progress or done.
How to resolve it ?

Comment: Why not creating one view for all states? Should be way easier than trying other things.

Comment: That's why, i'm trying to make it easier to maintenance

Comment: Yes that could be an argument, but Odoo's framework is limited. So either changing/extending the framework or a big ugly view to maintain are your options. ;-)